# Finding a subalgebra given a quotient algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I'm not sure my question is well-formed, but let me try.

Suppose we have the tensor algebra $T(V)$ (over a field of characteristic zero, to keep things simple). One thing we can do is look at the subalgebra of antisymmetric tensors. To do this, we can define an "antisymmetrizer," which maps a tensor to its antisymmetric form:

$$Alt(v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_n)
:=
\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sign}(\sigma) v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \ldots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$$

Then, we can introduce a symbol $\wedge$, where

$$v_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_n := Alt(v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_n)$$

Now, if we want to simplify an expression like $v_1 \wedge v_2 + v_2 \wedge v_1$, it's easy: we apply the given map and perform algebra in $T(V)$ and find that it's zero.

The other way to define $\wedge$ is to use a quotient algebra. Specifically, we look at the algebra $T(V)$ mod "the two-sided ideal generated by all elements of the form $x \otimes x$ for $x \in V$." Then, the symbol $\wedge$ represents an equivalence class in $T(V)$. Specifically:

$$v_1 \wedge v_2 = -(v_2 \wedge v_1)$$

Can be considered shorthand for:

$$v_1 \otimes v_2 \equiv -(v_2 \otimes v_1) (mod I)$$

But this gives us no way to simplify $v_1 \wedge v_2 + v_2 \wedge v_1$, other than to notice the above equivalence. This seems to make the subalgebra construction more useful. (First: is that true?)

Apparently not every quotient algebra of a given $A$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra, but when there is such an isomorphism, is there always a straightforward way to find something like $Alt$ above which "projects" elements of $A$ onto the subalgebra?

**Edit**: As Jyrki points out in the comments, what I've written isn't true. For example, $v_1 \in Alt(T(V))$ and $v_2 \in Alt(T(V))$ but $v_1\otimes v_2 \notin Alt(T(V))$, so this isn't a subalgebra. Nonetheless it is a sub*space*, and can be given an algebraic structure by defining $v_1 \wedge v_2 := Alt(v_1 \otimes v_2).$

So in its very definition, we've been provided with a map back to an algebra where we already know the rules. But that isn't so for the quotient map. We said that the symbol $v_1 \wedge v_2$ stands for an equivalence class, but we're not given a canonical member that allows you to perform algebra without any new rules.

In a vector space, you can get that canonical member by projecting along one subspace onto another. So I think I was trying to figure out whether there's a way use this idea of "projecting" along the ideal to get $Alt$.

Comment: I don't think the antisymmetric tensor form a subalgebra of $T(V)$. After all, any vector $v\in V$ is its own antisymmetrized version, but their tensor products are obviously not. The point here is that for something to be a *sub*algebra of $T(V)$ it should use the same product as the mother algebra.

Comment: In general, the quotient algebras are easy to work with regard to the universal properties. We first check that $T(V)$ has its universal property. Then *using its universal property* we can easily deduce the relevant universal properties of the quotient algebra be checking that the relevant is mapped to zero. I think that may be the reason why algebraists prefer the quotient algebra way of looking at these.

Comment: But, you can identify totally symmetric and totally anti-symmetric sub*spaces* of $T(V)$. Getting an algebra structure on those is a bit tricky though. IIRC you need those  [anti]symmetrizer, and then some weird multipliers.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So the antisymmetric tensors form a sub*space* of T(V) but it loses its algebraic structure (in particular, closure under product). Somehow I conflated the fact that we can create an algebra **on** that subspace with the idea that it is a subalgebra. I'll have to think harder about this, I guess. Is there anything general to learn from this example, or is the tensor algebra "special" in some easily-described way?

Comment: First: I thought the question was kinda cool, but posted in comments partly to seek clarification. The tensor algebra may be special in many ways, but we can always do something like the following.  Consider a quotient of algebras, like $A/I$ with $A$ an algebra over a field $K$, $I$ an ideal (and also a subspace). The elements of $A/I$ are naturally cosets of the subspace $I$. And we can always find a complementary subspace $Q$ such that $A=I\oplus Q$, when automatically every coset of $I$ gets identified with a single vector in  $Q$.

Comment: (cont'd)  In general there is no "natural" candidate for the complementary $Q$. Many subspaces can serve in that role. It is rare that one of them would be closed under the original product. In your example we do have a natural candidate for $Q$, and this could be seen as $T(V)$ being somewhat special. Unfortunately that subspace is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use the direct sum $\oplus$, two comments up , instead of the tensor product.

Comment: Thanks very much! So this is quite different from what happens in vector spaces, right? There, any V/U can always be naturally identified with a subspace W?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "noncommutative Gröbner bases". These allow you to reduce any element of a quotient algebra to a "normal form" which is guaranteed to be (visibly) $0$ if and only if the element is $0$. From what I remember, these bases don't always exist, but they do often enough to be useful.