# How to think about the tensor product symbol in the alternating tensor algebra

Tags: notation, tensor-products

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309732/finding-a-subalgebra-given-a-quotient-algebra) I made the mistake of thinking that the alternating tensor algebra was a subalgebra of the tensor algebra. Specifically, start with $T(V)$ and consider the "antisymmetrizer" map:

$$Alt(v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_n)
:=
\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sign}(\sigma) v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \ldots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$$

The image of this map is a subspace of $T(V)$ but is not a subalgebra: for any $v_1, v_2 \in V$, we have that both are in $Alt(V)$ but $v_1 \otimes v_2$ is not.

This is easily fixed by defining a product $v_1 \hat\otimes v_2 := Alt(v_1 \otimes v_2)$. What's giving me trouble is understanding how to think of the symbol $\otimes$ in the alternating algebra, given that it's not an operation.

On one hand, we could entirely banish it, so that whenever we write an element of the algebra $Alt(T(V))$ we are only allowed to use the symbol $\hat\otimes$. On the other hand, given the definition of that symbol, it seems perfectly legitimate to say that, e.g., $v_1 \otimes v_2 - v_2 \otimes v_1$ is an element of $Alt(T(V))$. In that case $\otimes$ becomes something of an uninterpreted symbol that only has meaning in certain contexts (e.g., we cannot make sense of "$v_1 \otimes v_2$" by itself, since it's not part of the algebra).

Perhaps my question is overly philosophical, but I feel it would help if I understood how mathematicians mentally "bucket" this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think we have to make $\otimes$ a second class citizen just because it doesn’t suit the alternating tensors.

We need to keep it around so that we can unpack the definition of the wedge product sometimes.

I just think of it as an operation on the tensors under which the alternating tensors are not closed. Rather than viewing this as a cause for dispair, I think it is interesting.

Comment: I think I figured out what's bothering me. Any algebra -- the alternating tensor / exterior algebra (which I guess are canonically isomorphic?) included -- can be defined without reference to other algebras. So we don't "need" to keep $\otimes$ around, but it's useful sometimes, right? Now, we "just happen" to have a map Alt: $T(V) \rightarrow A(V)$, but usually when we have a map we don't "export symbols" from one side to the other. So what's happening in my mind is that I'm interpreting $v_1 \hat\otimes v_2 := Alt(v_1 \otimes v_2)$ in two different ways: (cont'd)

Comment: one is as a *definition* of $\hat\otimes$ that depends on another algebra, and the other is as an incidental map between "unrelated" algebras that just helps me do some computations. And my mind is trying to figure out which interpretation is "correct," but that's perhaps meaningless.